# How can Scala IDE be uninstalled totally

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, software-uninstall, scala

I have installed an eclipse IDE with scala nature. And it is called the Scala-IDE from [scala-ide.org](http://scala-ide.org).

How can I uninstall Scala IDE on ubuntu?

I know that If it is a package we can by `sudo apt-get remove "package"`

But since it is downloaded as tar file. And there is no such uninstall option as that of windows... So, what should I do??

Comment: What exactly did you install? How did you install it?

Comment: I have installed an eclipse IDE with scala nature... And it is called the Scala-IDE from this site(http://scala-ide.org/). When we download... It automatically gets the eclipse launcher in it. When we run it the application gets launched.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Yaron. Have any solution for me??

Answer (score 0):

The Scala IDE is not installed nor removed. It is just a package of files that you copy to a directory that you create.

Delete the directory that you created for the Scala IDE files. The IDE is now gone.